# Ruby on rails searching arrays (Active record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model with an array column. So I'm basically saving languages as an array to Postgres. For example, `driver_language =["English", "Spanish", "French"]`

In my Query, I want to select all vehicles where `submitted_driver_language ["English", "Spanish"]` is included in driver_language. Or at least one element of the submitted driver_language array is included in the driver_language column which is an array. How can I add that condition to the query below? Any help will be appreciated

```
Vehicle.where(:vehicle_type => vehicle_type, :active => true, :company_activated => true, :capacity => number_of_people.to_i..Float::INFINITY)
```

Comment: Do you store the language as a [PostgreSQL array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) or just as a string in your database. You don't you normalize your data, create a languages table and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

Answer (score 0):

Use arel_table.

```
@vehicle = Vehicle.where(:vehicle_type => vehicle_type, :active => true, :company_activated => true, :capacity => number_of_people.to_i..Float::INFINITY)

avehicle = @vehicle.arel_table

@required_result = @vehicle.where(avehicle[:driver_language].matches('%#{"English", "Spanish"}%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex?

```
Vehicle.where('driver_language ~* ?', 'english|spanish')
```